# PHP echo an HTML table with alternate quote marks

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use PHP echo to call a big styled HTML table that someone has provided for me. The problem that I'm encountering is the HTML tables was coded with both double quotes ("") and single quotes ('') when defining classes and arguments/parameters. I'm able to get the table to display properly if I take a long time to change everything to single or double quotes, but is there an easier way to display the table without doing this?

Here is an example of a smaller table that has been provided for me: **Please note the alternate ' and "**

```
<div class='ws-schedule' id='ws-schedule1'>
<table>
<tr class='topheader'><th class='rowheader'></th><th>11am</th><th>12pm</th><th>1pm</th><th>2pm</th><th>3pm</th><th>4pm</th><th>5pm</th><th>6pm</th><th>7pm</th><th>8pm</th></tr>
<tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Sun</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='Work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">Work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='Gym' id='continueright' colspan='2' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">Gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Mon</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='Work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">Work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='Gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Tue</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Wed</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Thu</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='Possible work day//' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">Possible Work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Fri</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td></tr><tr class='row1'>
<th rowspan='1' class='rowheader'>Sat</th>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#FFA100;"tooltip='work' colspan='4' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">work</div></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="ws-item-1" style= "background-color:#0074A2;"tooltip='gym' colspan='1' class='cat1'><div class="ws-item-title ws-item-title-1">gym</div></td><td></td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: how about heredoc? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Mixing your quotes between single and double ones in plain HTML mark up is just asking for problems... correct the markup and stick to one quotation. If you ask me, double quotes are neater for HTML. Changing the quotes in this piece of code you showed won't take long...

Comment: I don’t see a single piece of PHP code inside your table (output of variables or anything) – so there’s probably no need to output it via PHP in the first place. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: If this is just a provided static table, why on earth would you need to echo it????

Comment: You may consider looking into the use of PHP's `preg_replace`- you can use a RegEx to change all singles to doubles or the other way around. Quite likely to cause tears if you try to do it to something containing JS with mixed quote styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) as @Dagon suggests:

```
$tableHTML = <<<TABLE_HTML
<div class='ws-schedule' id='ws-schedule1'>
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
TABLE_HTML;
```

However, I'm not sure you should do this in this instance. This is provided to you statically. Presumably youre not add any PHP output to the table (otherwise why not just fix it while youre in there?) so I would just pull the content from the file similar to if you use `file_get_contents()`:

```
function file_get_contents_php($file, array $vars = null) {

   if (null !== $vars) {
      extract($vars);
   }

   ob_start();
   include($file);
   $html = ob_get_clean();
   return $html;
}
```

Usage would look like:

```
$tableHTML = file_get_contents_php('path/to/table.html');
```

This gets you the markup as a single string, and it keeps this table isolated so its not the random big string in your block of code which will make it **much** easier to update.

I'd do it this way instead of using `file_get_contents()` because this way if you ever need to add a bit of php to it you can:

```
$tableHTML = file_get_contents_php('path/to/table.html', array(
    'title' => 'A variable to be referenced by $title in table.html'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your IDE to add slash before the qoute by using find And replace

For example if you want to use double qoute 
echo "text 'text' \"test\" text";

Hope this helps